# JSTL Spring MVC Recursive Form JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, jstl

I am trying to build a dynamic form generator getting a json as an input. The json comes from an AWS device shadow and I want to build a form which allows the user to manipulate the desired state of it.

The controller class looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class FormGeneratorController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/form/textfield", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"parentName", "propertyName", "propertyValue"})
    public ModelAndView getTextField(@RequestParam(value = "parentName", required = false, defaultValue = "") String parentName,
                                @RequestParam(value = "propertyName", required = false, defaultValue = "") String propertyName,
                                @RequestParam(value = "propertyValue", required = false, defaultValue = "") String propertyValue) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("jsonConfigTextField");
        model.addObject("parentName", parentName);
        model.addObject("propertyName", propertyName);
        model.addObject("propertyValue", propertyValue);

        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/form/objectfield", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"parentName", "propertyName", "propertyValue"})
    public ModelAndView getObjectField(@RequestParam(value = "parentName", required = false, defaultValue = "") String parentName,
                                        @RequestParam(value = "propertyName", required = false, defaultValue = "") String propertyName,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "propertyValue", required = false, defaultValue = "") String propertyValue) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("jsonConfigObjectField");
        JSONObject settings = new JSONObject(propertyValue);
        model.addObject("parentName", parentName);
        model.addObject("propertyName", propertyName);
        model.addObject("propertyValue", settings);

        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getForm() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("settingsForm");
        model.addObject("parentName", "");
        model.addObject("propertyName", "root");
        model.addObject("propertyValue", "{\"light\":{\"test\":\"t\"}}");
        return model;
    }
}
```

settingsForm.jsp:

```
<form>
    <c:import url="/form/objectfield?parentName=${parentName}&propertyName=${propertyName}&propertyValue=${propertyValue}"></c:import>
    <input type="submit" value="Absenden"> 
</form>
```

jsonObjectField.jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${propertyValue.keys()}" var="propertyKey">
        <c:if test="${propertyValue.get(propertyKey).getClass().name == 'java.lang.String'}">
            <c:import url="/form/textfield?parentName=${parentName}&propertyName=${propertyKey}&propertyValue=${propertyValue.getString(propertyKey)}" ></c:import>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${propertyValue.get(propertyKey).getClass().name == 'org.json.JSONObject'}">
            <c:import url="/form/objectfield?parentName=${parentName}&propertyName=${propertyKey}&propertyValue=${propertyValue.getJSONObject(propertyKey)}" ></c:import>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
```

jsonConfigTextField.jsp:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="<c:out value="${parentName}_${propertyName}"></c:out>"><c:out value="${parentName}_${propertyName}"></c:out></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="${parentName}_${propertyName}" name="${parentName}_${propertyName}" value="${propertyValue}">
</div>
```

This produces:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for=",,,_test,light,root">test,light,root</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id=",,,_test,light,root" name=",,,_test,light,root" value="t,{"test":"t"},{"light":{"test":"t"}}">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Absenden"> 
</form>
```

But I want to generate a form like this:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="root_light_test">root_light_test</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="root_light_test" name="root_light_test" value="t">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Absenden"> 
</form>
```

It seems like there is a problem with the JSONObject within in a JSONObject where the recursion I thought I would be doing somehow goes wrong. I do not understand where all the commas in the output are comming from.
Since recreating the issue is pretty hard I created a repository for you to clone and test the thing for yourself: https://github.com/faxe1008/JSTLRecursiveForm

I really would appreciate any help on this, today I spent 4 hours trying to figure out the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the JSON input in your controller, with Jackson for example, and add the data to simple objects. These you should pass to your model, which is available in your view. In you view simply iterate the created objects

Comment: Is it possible to give those simpleobject a toString() method which uses a modelandview to use jsp templates or do I have to insert the HTML into the simpleobject itself?

Comment: No. There no json parser in jstl.

Comment: No thats not what I meant. I wondered if you can use the .jsp files as templates, similar to how they are used in controllers, which will be used inside a for example textFieldForm simpleobjects toString() method?

Comment: Do you want iterate propertyValue from jsp?

Comment: That was my question - I do not know if that is the best way to tackle it

Comment: You must convert propertyValue  as a java object and iterate using jstl or propertyValue  should be comma seperated then you can use jstl split function.